# Unable to edit my response to a locked question

Tags: support, status-declined, edits, historical-lock

The image is broken in my [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/677797/23566) to the "favorite programmer cartoon" question. I'd be happy to fix this, but I can't (not enough rep? not a moderator?).

Here's the image in the Internet Archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20120308105047/http://www.bemroses.net/images/curves.jpg

Answer (score 4):

The historical lock notices emphasizes:

> **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**

That said, we could try and keep up the post, but then we'd be diverting energy away from maintaining *other* aspects of the site that *are* good fits for the site.

To that end, please don't flag moderators or post to meta to to have it unlocked so you can perform edits/changes, it's simply not worth everyone's time.

It's also my opinion that over time, historical locks should lead to deletions, as the usefulness of the content on the page will eventually rot away (quality/content-wise) and the primary condition for the lock (that the content be of value) will no longer be applicable.

Your request is an example of that; the link is broken, and we have a broken window on the site.

I'd personally be more inclined to delete the answer, as editing it makes no sense; Stack Exchange is not the place to archive this content.  Your blog or other medium is a better choice if you're worried about the content being preserved beyond its usefulness.

Comment: Too bad. I understand the motivation to filter questions like this going forward, but letting it die a slow death is hardly a good policy.

Comment: @RobertClaypool The only other option is to delete the post.  You have to make the decision between "is this post in its entirety more important than all the broken aspects of it?" Eventually the answer is going to be "no" at which point, we're going to delete it.  Consider it the Stack Exchange representation of entropy.

Answer (score 1):

Only moderators can change locked questions and their answers.

Besides, the question is an historical example (we used to accept this but now we are wiser). So no need to edit a broken link.

And if you really want it fixed, you can flag this question and link to your answer. No success guaranteed.

Comment: There's always a need for cleanup, but flagging is probably the only solution here.  That questions still probably draws a lot of people in.

Comment: The question has a historical lock, you can't flag in this case.

Comment: @MadScientist, that's why I said flag this question and link... ;-).